React Hook Form at Least One TextField Has Value
I have 2 controlled inputs on a form, and I only need to validate that 1 of them is filled in. I'm having trouble with the validation logic.
                   function atLeastOneChecked(inputs: string) {
                       return inputs.length > 0;
                   }

                   <Controller
                        control={control}
                        {...register("phoneNumber", {
                            validate: atLeastOneChecked,
                        })}
                        render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
                            <TextField
                                {...field}
                                label="Phone Number"
                                error={!!error}
                                helperText={!!error && 'Phone or email required.'}
                            />
                        )}
                    />
                    <Controller
                        control={control}
                        {...register("email", {
                            validate: atLeastOneMediumChecked,
                        })}
                        render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
                            <TextField
                                {...field}
                                label="Email"
                                error={!!error}
                                helperText={!!error && 'Phone or email required.'}
                            />
                        )}
                    />

When I submit, the validation function gets called twice, once for each component. So it works the same as required: true on each one.
What I need is for the validate function to check both at once, and only return an error if both are empty.
I have tried:
                   function atLeastOneChecked(inputs: Inputs) {
                       

and
                   function atLeastOneChecked(inputs: string[]) {

But then the validate property throws an error that the types are incompatible.

The answer to this was to use a resolver:
const { handleSubmit, control, register, formState: { errors } } = useForm<Inputs>({
        defaultValues: {
            ...defaultValues,
        },
        resolver: data => {
            const error: FieldErrors = {} as FieldErrors;

            if (!data.phoneNumber.trim() && !data.email.trim()) {
                const message = 'Either Phone Number or Email is required.';
                error.phoneNumberParam = error.emailParam = { message: message, type: '' };
            }

            return {
                values: data,
                errors: error,
            };
        },
    });

